# how to sync Packages and settings for multiple computer in Github Atom Editor

Tags: github, atom-editor

I have installed Github Atom Editor in my Personal PC and Office PC.
I want to sync the settings and packages to my dropbox account so when i log in the office PC it automatically download or update all the packages and settings to my Home PC

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried to use [Atom Sync Settings](https://atom.io/packages/sync-settings) instead? It does the job for me.

Comment: Is there some other way?

Comment: @DamjanPavlica i didnt find any other

Comment: @DamjanPavlica Other workaround would be to push all the necessary atom files to your git repository & make subsequent pushes as & when you make changes in the atom settings. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877289/how-to-share-transfer-an-atom-installation-packages-and-settings-from-one-mac)

Comment: @DamjanPavlica You can use [package-sync](https://atom.io/packages/package-sync) in combination with Git. I simply added the relevant files to [my homegit](https://github.com/thutterer/homegit)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't absolutely need Dropbox, [atom-package-sync](https://atom.io/packages/atom-package-sync) is a package that I created a couple weeks ago. It works a little bit like the synchronization of Google Chrome, you just login and it syncs your packages and settings automatically across all your Atom instances.

[image]

I plan to release the source code for the server side in the coming weeks and add an export feature for alternative backups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [package-sync](https://atom.io/packages/package-sync) in combination with Git. I simply added the relevant files to [my homegit](https://github.com/thutterer/homegit/tree/master/.atom).