# Change default path for Atom Key Bindings keymap.cson file

Tags: configuration, cloud, key-bindings, atom-editor

I configured all my key bindings for Atom Editor in `keymap.cson` which is located in `C:\Users\Username\.atom\keymap.cson` but I need to syncronise it with `Dropbox` or `Google Drive` folder to future headakes if I reinstall OS or editor.

So, how to configure Atom to read `Keymap.cson` file from different location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a package like https://atom.io/packages/sync-settings for syncing settings across multiple computers. This uses a Gist on GitHub to store your settings.

Also check out this answer, which goes in the same direction, but also talks about syncing installed packages. There are several options listed in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30972738/1228454