# Atom editor install from git for multiple machines

Tags: github, atom-editor

I am trying to utilise this post to install Atom with same settings.

[How to share/transfer an Atom installation (packages and settings) from one Mac to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877289/how-to-share-transfer-an-atom-installation-packages-and-settings-from-one-mac)

I created the repo here 
 https://github.com/alanauckland86/atom

this was from my Mac machine.

I have tried to clone this into my Windows machine. 
I renamed the package same as install folder and cloned the repo into the default location.

When I install Atom the files get completely over written. 
I tried copying the files into the Atom folder for Git, that didn't work! Git looses its place and can't find itself.

I have only ever used Source tree and Github's editors for using Git. 
All the commands I have read for trying to solve this boggles me a bit.

Comment: As suggested in the post, you could try to use the sync-settings package (https://atom.io/packages/sync-settings). I'm using it and it works like a charm.

Comment: I followed the instructions for the sync-settings. 
Created a gist and pushed it up.

I have installed syn-settings on the other machine. I entered the gist ID (after my usernamd)

Comment: I installed sync-settings and followed set up instructions. 

I am now on the other machine I want to sync with the gist. 
I input the gist ID. 
Do I have to create a second personal access token for this machine as well for it to work?

Comment: No I think you can use the same