# Moving atom settings and plugins to another computer

Tags: linux, ide, atom-editor

I've played around with Atom for a while and got the plugins I want to use, the look and feel, etc. Is there a way to copy my exact setup on my Mac to my Linux laptop?

Comment: You could try the following. Its been asked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877289/how-to-share-transfer-an-atom-installation-packages-and-settings-from-one-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following. Its been asked before:

[How to share/transfer an Atom installation (packages and settings) from one Mac to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877289/how-to-share-transfer-an-atom-installation-packages-and-settings-from-one-mac)

It might be overkill for your need but you could also use [sync settings](https://atom.io/packages/sync-settings). This requires you to use a gist to sync between installations.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yeah I think this will def work great

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I looked for the same a few time ago and I found this:

https://discuss.atom.io/t/is-there-a-method-to-import-export-settings/10616